# Meaning of 白分 in Whatsapp

Tags: kanji, japanese-to-english

I set my phone's language into Japanese to make me more exposed to the Japanese language. Therefore, many apps also turned into Japanese, following the system's language.

I have searched for a lot of kanji and words I can find on my phone, but there is this word written in kanji 白分 (shiro bun)?

I don't really know how to read it but I know the kanji. I can guest the meaning but I am not sure. So I wonder if anyone knows what it means and how to read the word.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word is most likely not 白分, but 自分{じぶん}, meaning 'self'. In the context of an app, it refers to you, the user.

Comment: Ahh, that's right. Thank you for the great answer. I have checked it again and it turns out to be 自分。